# Вывод сравнение таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql

если есть две записи в таблице, допустим в dating:
1 запись (id=1, user_id=10, user_id_from=14)
2 запись (id=2, user_id=14, user_id_from=10)
это значит что у пользователей совпали лайки, то, мы создаем им диалог. или делаем что то еще. как это реализовать?

Comment: А что сложного ? Проверили 2 таблицы, нашли совпадения - выполнили нужный участок кода...

Comment: таблица одна и та же. просто записывается для одного пользователя, и для второго пользователя.

Comment: и здесь https://requ.tech/dating.php надо вывести пары. если есть запись моя с моим айди и айди кому я поставил лайк. и если есть запись где айди пользователя и мой айди где он поставил лайк.